# Update MongoDB hash field name in array

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with items like that:

```
_id: object id
h: value
w: value
v: array
     {
         p: value
         n: value
         c: array
     },
     {
     },...
```

I want to rename the `d` field of all `values` of all items to something else, let's say `f`.

How can that be done? (Basically, can it be done?)

Comment: Have you taken a look here? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-method-examples

Comment: This sounds like a job for [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/index.html#rename)

Comment: @maxpleaner Yes, I have. But I'm still confused.

Comment: @Joe That was my initial guess. However, my case looks a bit more complicated: I'm not talking about modifying main field keys, but nested keys within an array structure...

Comment: ah, I didn't see `d` in the sample document, and so didn't realize it was in the array.  You might be able to manage this with aggregation, if you are using MongoDB 4.2

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be interested, this is exactly how I did it (MongoDB version: 3.6.3)

```
db.getCollection('COLLECTION_NAME').find({"v": { $exists : 1 }}).forEach(
    function( doc ){

        for( i=0; i < doc.v.length; ++i ) {
            doc.v[i].f = doc.v[i].c;
            delete doc.v[i].c;
        }

        db.getCollection('COLLECTION_NAME').update(
         { _id : doc._id }
         , doc 
        );
    }
);
```